# How to create a 7 character underline input text field in html and css(screenshot attached)?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

[image]

I am creating an UI for a mobile app I am required to create a popover with the UI attached in the screenshot.How to create a 7 character underline input text field in html and css like the below one?

---

HTML Code

```
<ion-modal-view class="modal contact-details-modal" id="contactDetailModal">



<ion-content delegate-handle="modalContent">   
<center>
<br><br>
<img src="assets/images/camera-small.png">  
<br><p>Camera</p>
     <div class="underline_camera" style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid  #b2b2b2;outline: 0;width: 100px;">
    <input type="text" id="camera" name=" camera" value="" />
</div><br>

<div class="meter_reading" style="border: 0;border-bottom: 1px solid     #b2b2b2;outline: 0;width: 20px;">
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <!--<input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="meter" name=" meter" value="" />-->

 </div>


 <div class="button-bar">

 <a class="button button-balanced">
 SUBMIT</a>
 </div> 
 </center>
</ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

CSS Code

```
.contact-details-modal {
   top: 15%;
   border-radius: 3px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
   min-height: 70% !important;
   width: 80%;
   left: 10%;
}
```

Answer (score 48):

Here's a solution that creates a single text field with underlines under each character (try deleting and writing another number in the `input` field):

```css
input {
  border: none;
  width: 10.5ch;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
        dimgrey 0, 
        dimgrey 1ch, 
        transparent 0, 
        transparent 1.5ch) 
      0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  color: dimgrey;
  font: 5ch consolas, monospace;
  letter-spacing: .5ch;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<input maxlength='7' value='0123456'/>
```

This uses [**the `ch` unit**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ch) whose width is the width of the `0` character. It also assumes the font in the `input` field is a monospace one so that all characters have the same width.

So the width for every character is always `1ch`. The gap between the characters is taken to be `.5ch`. This is the value we set for `letter-spacing`. The `width` of the `input` is the number of characters times the sum between the letter width (`1ch`) and the gap width (`.5ch`). So that's `7*(1ch + .5ch) = 7*1.5ch = 10.5ch`.

We remove the actual `border` of the `input` and we set a fake one using a `repeating-linear-gradient`. The dash (`dimgrey`) goes from `0` to `1ch` and the gap (`transparent`) starts immediately after the dash and goes to `1.5ch`.

It's attached to the left and the bottom of the input - this is the `background-position` component (`0%` horizontally and `100%` vertically).

It spreads across the entire input horizontally (`100%`) and is `2px` tall - this is the `background-size` component of the `background`.

The Sass code that generates this CSS is:

```
$char-w: 1ch;
$gap: .5*$char-w;
$n-char: 7;
$in-w: $n-char*($char-w + $gap);

input {
  border: none;
  width: $in-w;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, 
    dimgrey 0, dimgrey $char-w, 
    transparent 0, transparent $char-w + $gap) 
    0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  font: 5ch consolas, monospace;
  letter-spacing: $gap;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: dodgerblue;
  }
}
```

You can tweak the gap and other things [**here**](https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/mRrPwB/?editors=1100).

Comment: This is so clever!

Comment: This is the best solution I have come across.

Answer (score 2):

Add a max length of character to an input.

```
<input type="text" class="underline" maxlength="7">
```

Adding `size="7"` is an easy way of also setting the width of the input to contain the 7 characters. But it's better to handle this in CSS.

And give it the proper styling.

```
.underline {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: thin solid gray;
}
```

First I set `border` to 0 to remove all border styling, after which I set styling for `border-bottom`. This way it takes only two lines of code instead of four when styling all border top, right, bottom and left.

**Update**
https://jsfiddle.net/1q3h8qeh/

Comment: please I want the feel of the screenshot i have attached , each text field contains 1 integer

Comment: your updated solution worked but one question i have other forms and text fields in other places , the width of this form element is overriding the width property of other forms . Please suggest a solution

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/1645981/paul-van-den-dool the width property of the the form in your updated solution is overriding the width properties of other form elements. I have another form in another page. Please suggest a solution. Can form have class or id ? I am a newbie

Comment: You could use an id on the form yes. If you'll use the styling on more forms you should use a class. Also put the form class or id before the input styling so the styling only applies to the inputs inside the form.

Comment: Backspace does not work